kotlin multi platform project's podspec file spec.script_phases gets changed when syncing Android Studio and brakes pod installatioon
I'm working on a Kotlin multi platform library and it has a podspec file and its spec.script_phases is
    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build kotlin_mpp',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT/.." $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration=$CONFIGURATION \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.cflags="$OTHER_CFLAGS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.headers="$HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.frameworks="$FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS"

            SCRIPT
        }
    ]

the problem is that every time Android studio syncs (also when the computer gets turned on) it changes it to
    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build kotlin_mpp',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]

Now this breaks the Xcode build after I run pod install with error

* What went wrong:
Script compilation errors:

  Line 14:     alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
                     ^ Unresolved reference: libs

  Line 15:     alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods)
                     ^ Unresolved reference: libs

  Line 16:     alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
                     ^ Unresolved reference: libs

  Line 18:     alias(libs.plugins.sqldelight)
                     ^ Unresolved reference: libs

  Line 19:     alias(libs.plugins.kotlinSerialization)
                     ^ Unresolved reference: libs

  Line 20:     alias(libs.plugins.openapigen)
                     ^ Unresolved reference: libs

I have to discard changes on the file in order to make it work again.
I noticed that if start a new project then the podspec file gets created with this (new) scrip_phase.
Is there a way to avoid this and leave the podspec file as it is (with the original script_phase) or should I make some changes in the Xcode project Podfile to accomodate for this changed script_phase?
In it it's just enabled use_frameworks! and a path to kotlin project is declared as
  use_frameworks!
  inhibit_all_warnings!
  pod 'kotlin_mpp', :path => './kotlin-mpp/kotlin-mpp'


...

Many thanks for your help
